# Error in my live app when navigating admin interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, admin

When I navigate to a certain resource in the admin interface for my app I get a status 500 error. Why might this be?

Here is from my logs:

```
2011-06-16T21:33:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/admin/timeline_events" for 151.205.162.106 at 2011-06-16 14:33:35 -0700
2011-06-16T21:33:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-06-16T21:33:35+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass):
```

How would I find where `map` is in my app?

OK, so I think it's this code in my application helper that might be causing this

```
def render_timeline(events, title)
  events.map do |event|
    render(:partial => "timeline_events/#{event.event_type}", :locals => {:event => event, :title => title})
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

The code basically renders different partials depending on what type of event it is to create a feed.

Comment: Is there any more details you could provide so that we have something more specific to work with? This is an extremely vague question

Comment: I'm really unsure where to look. What else might I provide?

Comment: Your calling map in one of your controllers or views. Give us those.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding it

Comment: ok I think I might have found it

Comment: Which controller/action is mapped to '/admin/timeline_events'. Please post the code from this action.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're calling the method but passing `nil` as the `events` argument.

Make sure that when there are no events to be rendered, you pass in an empty array instead of `nil`.

You can catch this in the body of the method by adding:

```
events ||= []
```

as the first line, or you can use default arguments:

```
def render_timeline(events = [], title)
```

or you can just change how you generate the `events` argument so it never returns `nil`.

Comment: top two, I even tried adding `unless events.nil?` and that didn't work either, so this is probably not where the error is

Comment: Yeah, it must be happening somewhere else. Look for another place you're calling `map` on an object and make sure there's no way the object can be `nil`. The same steps should apply.